# Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop 'Find in Files' output to Find Results 2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express

I'm having issues using 'Find in Files' in VS2013 for Windows Desktop. Find results are not displaying in the 'Find Results' window.

Searching Google and StackOverflow shows people have had issues where it displays a count of results but no actual list. There also appears to be an issue where the window is 'blocked' and pressing ctrl+break (or other combinations) unblocks it. This issue appears to be different, hence raising it as a new question.

'Replace in Files' still half works (replaces the text but doesn't list the changes as it used to) which indicates that the logic is still working.

When performing the find or replace the info bar at the bottom flashes up the details:

'Find all "*search string*", Subfolders, Keep modified files open, Find Results 2, Entire Solution, "*.*"

It's the 'Find Results 2' part that I think is causing the problem. The Express version of VS doesn't have the 2 separate results windows (or any option to specify which one to output to). Somehow it appears to have been set to 2 instead of 1. I've tried a repair of my install with no success. Does anyone know how I can get VS to revert to outputting to 1?

Comment: I've managed to solve this is a less than ideal way, I would still appreciate any better solutions.
I replaced C:\Users\*username*\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Settings\WD Express\CurrentSettings.vssettings with the same CurrentSettings.vssettings file from VS 2010 C# Express. It moved all my windows around to how I had them under 2010 but find now outputs to 'Find Results 1' so I think my hunch was correct. I will seek a solution that does stomp over all other settings to fix this minor issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+F -> Show dropdown -> Find in files -> Result options -> Find results 1 window